# How to create an inline variable in a vue.js 3 template

Tags: vue.js

So I am trying to create a dynamic show hide property on my comment section, basically I have it currently working with a plain JavaScript method using events, however I presume there is an easier way using the vue.js framework. What I want to do is either create an inline variable or add to an existing variable which has a default value of false, then I can change it based on a click using the @click directive. from an older post on stackoverflow I can across a :set directive but it seems it isn't working as expected.

```
<div v-if="comments.data" :key="comment.id"
         v-for="(comment, index) in comments.data"
         :set="editComment[comment.id] = false">
        <hr>
        <p v-show="editComment[comment.id]">{{ comment.comment }}</p>
        <div v-if="$page.props.auth.user.id === comment.user.id" >
            <form @submit.prevent class="edit-form" v-show="editComment[comment.id]">
                <textarea
                      class="form-control" rows="4" minlength="4">{{ comment.comment }}</textarea>
            </form>
            <div class="buttons">
                <button id="update" v-show="editComment[comment.id]" class="btn btn-primary" @click="updateComment(index, $event)">Update Comment</button>
                <button id="cancel" v-show="editComment[comment.id]" class="btn btn-primary">Cancel</button>
                <button id="edit" v-show="!editComment[comment.id]" class="btn btn-primary" @click="editComment[comment.id] = true">Edit Comment</button>
                <button id="delete" class="btn btn-danger" @click="deleteComment(index)">Delete Comment</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: What issue you are facing in above code ?

Comment: Well it doesn't do anything. The ide also doesn't recognise the :set function either